# What does R mean by "prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading"

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I am running binary logistic regression on class data with "yes" as the predictor.  I have train/test and running the pred function for both and I get this error  message.  Anyone know what it is alluding to?  Most of my variables are logical "Yes/No", one is Sex (M/F).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558631/predict-lm-in-a-loop-warning-prediction-from-a-rank-deficient-fit-may-be-mis

Comment: Welcome to the site Kathleen! For future reference your question is probably better placed on stackoverflow rather than crossvalidated since it is about a programming error. I think my above comment should lead you to a solution.

Comment: @André.B the message looks to be statistical in nature, rather than a code syntax error or exception message. Most coding errors do not discuss whether a fit is rank deficient, so this seems to be the proper place for this specific question. Kathleen, would you please post a small amount of data as an example?

Comment: Kathleens question has already been answered on stackoverflow. See the above link.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I discovered that two of my variables (yes/no) had the exact same responses.  The variables were closely related anyway and clinicians were answering the same way for both as a result.